# ffmpeg fails to generate screenshots

Tags: video, ffmpeg, screenshot

I have a video file and I'm trying to generate screenshots from it.
When I use this command
`ffmpeg -ss 500 -i video_file.mp4  -frames:v 1 -y -s 263*196 output_screenshot.jpg`
a screenshot is generated just fine.

When I try with
`ffmpeg -ss 900 -i video_file.mp4  -frames:v 1 -y -s 263*196 output_screenshot.jpg`
(so 900 instead of 500) I get this error
`ffmpeg -ss 900 -i video_file.mp4  -frames:v 1 -y -s 263*196 output_screenshot.jpg
ffmpeg version git-2014-03-11-61f96be Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 11 2014 14:16:57 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-pthreads --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfaac --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libfreetype
  libavutil      52. 66.101 / 52. 66.101
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavdevice    55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavfilter     4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video_file.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2014-04-19 13:56:05
    title           : My Movie
    artist          :

    media_type      : 9
    season_number   : 1
    episode_sort    : 1
    hd_video        : 0
  Duration: 00:25:45.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1242 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 2586 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 58 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-19 13:56:05
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-19 13:56:05
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[swscaler @ 0x332d880] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'output_screenshot.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp41
    hd_video        : 0
    title           : My Movie
    artist          :

    media_type      : 9
    season_number   : 1
    episode_sort    : 1
    encoder         : Lavf55.34.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 263x196 [SAR 294:263 DAR 3:2], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-04-19 13:56:05
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mjpeg)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A

video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.000000%
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)`

and no screenshot is created. I mention that the file is 25min (about 1500 seconds) so 900 should be a perfectly fine value.
Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Does it work when you put the `-ss` part *after* the input file?

Comment: @slhck no, it will also fail but it will take much more time till it fails.

Comment: Have you checked if the input is actually playable up to that point? I sometimes forget to look at the actual material :)

Comment: @slhck Damn!:) You're so right, that was it, the file reported being some 1500seconds long but it was actually truncated thus the impossibility of generating the screenshots

Comment: Oh ok. So problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't get an output file, ffmpeg probably cannot seek to that position, or there is no video information at that position.

This means that the file could be broken, or the duration is just incorrectly reported from the container.

Try to play the file and see if it really works until 900 seconds.